# Fallback support nvidia libraries

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I'm planning to use GPU to do an application with intensive matrix manipulation. I want to use the CUDA NVIDIA support. My only doubt is: is there any fallback support? I mean: if I use these libraries I've got the possibility to run the application in non-CUDA environment (without gpu support, of course)? I'd like to have the possibility to debug the application without the constraint to use that environment. I didn't find this information, any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no fallback support built into the libraries (e.g. CUBLAS, CUSPARSE, CUFFT).  You would need to have your code develop a check for an existing CUDA environment, and if it finds none, then develop your own code path, perhaps using alternate libraries.  For example, CUBLAS functions can be mostly duplicated by other BLAS libraries (e.g. MKL).  CUFFT functions can be largely replaced by other FFT libraries (e.g. FFTW).

How to detect a CUDA environment is covered in other SO questions.  In a nutshell, if your application bundles (e.g. static-links) the CUDART library, then you can run a procedure similar to that in the [deviceQuery](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#device-query) sample code, to determine what GPUs (if any) are available.